# Issues with Leaflet, map not showing up and wont allow me to zoom out

Tags: leaflet, geojson

so I'm trying to complete the chloropleth map tutorial from Leaflet but the only thing showing up is the mapbox and nothing else. Any ideas as to why, ive changed browsers from safari to firefox and that didn't help any other ideas? Thanks a bunch!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <title>
            The Map
        </title>
        <!--Leaflet-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/Leaflet/leaflet.css"/>
        <script src="lib/Leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="data/states.geojson"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        #map{height:400px;}
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Breweries Per Capita in the US</h1>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
            var map = L.map('map');
            var statesLayer = L.geoJson(states).addTo(map).setView([36.688938, -101.340000],13);


             L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
    }).addTo(map);
        </script>

    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Your first meta tag is opened. Is it opened in project code to?

Comment: What is the value of your `states` variable? How does a `console.log(states);` look like?

Comment: Did you try check some errors in developer console in firefox or in other browsers?

Answer (score 0):

1. As stated by Anton Stepanenkov, your first `<meta` tag is not properly closed.
2. As suggested by IvanSanchez, you load a `.geojson` file which, if compliant with `json` spec, does not assign any variable but should instead be typically loaded through AJAX. Therefore there is a high chance your `states` variable is `undefined`. If your `.geojson` file does assign `states` (e.g. it contains a statement like `var states = {...};`), then you should rather rename your file with `.js` extension, as it is rather a classic JavaScript file.
3. [`setView`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-setview) is an `L.Map` method, you cannot chain it with `L.geoJson`.
4. Your mapbox Tile Layer URL template does not seem to work (maybe an issue with the access key?)

Working demo after closing the meta tag, taking out the `states`, applying `setView` on `map` and using another Tile Layer: http://plnkr.co/edit/G1D05GV68IXUlwlv9Pnw?p=preview

Comment: This worked perfectly, so thank you! Now the question is since I can't chain L.map with L.geojson, how do i go about displaying the data that is contained within my Geojson file?

Comment: Like what you have done and what is described here, and implemented in the provided demo: `L.geoJSON(data).addTo(map); map.setView(center, zoom)` or `map.fitBounds(geoJsonGroup.getBounds())` Make sure to read [Leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html)